# Getting the ScrollPosition of a RichEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

I have Windows Store app with a RichEditBox. I need to get the scroll position programmatically in order to match the scroll position on a grid along side it.

I can't find any documentation on how to do this online. In XAML I can set the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode and ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode, but there's no OnScroll event and no VerticalOffset

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Try parsing the visual tree. [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) lets you do this easily by doing something like `myRichEditTextBox.GetFirstDescendentOfType<ScrollViewer>()`.

Comment: thanks Nate. This worked for getting the ScrollPosition, however I can't seem to assign an event to the `Scroll` event of the Scrollbar contained within ScrollViewer. I guess this is a separate question really. If you want to submit the above as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Maybe try some of the Manipulation-based events?

Comment: It works if I target the ViewChanged event of the ScrollViewer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing the visual tree. [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) lets you do this easily by doing something like `myRichEditTextBox.GetFirstDescendentOfType<ScrollViewer>()`.